# Is there a way to test for enum value in a list of candidates? (Java)

Tags: java

This is a simplified example. I have this enum declaration as follows:

```
public enum ELogLevel {
    None,
    Debug,
    Info,
    Error
}
```

I have this code in another class:

```
if ((CLog._logLevel == ELogLevel.Info) || (CLog._logLevel == ELogLevel.Debug) || (CLog._logLevel == ELogLevel.Error)) {
    System.out.println(formatMessage(message));
}
```

My question is if there is a way to shorten the test.  Ideally i would like somethign to the tune of (this is borrowed from Pascal/Delphi):

```
if (CLog._logLevel in [ELogLevel.Info, ELogLevel.Debug, ELogLevel.Error])
```

Instead of the long list of comparisons. Is there such a thing in Java, or maybe a way to achieve it?  I am using a trivial example, my intention is to find out if there is a pattern so I can do these types of tests with enum value lists of many more elements.

**EDIT:** It looks like EnumSet is the closest thing to what I want. The Naïve way of implementing it is via something like:

```
if (EnumSet.of(ELogLevel.Info, ELogLevel.Debug, ELogLevel.Error).contains(CLog._logLevel))
```

But under benchmarking, this performs two orders of magnitude slower than the long if/then statement, I guess because the EnumSet is being instantiated every time it runs. This is a problem only for code that runs very often, and even then it's a very minor problem, since over 100M iterations we are talking about 7ms vs 450ms on my box; a very minimal amount of time either way.

What I settled on for code that runs very often is to pre-instantiate the EnumSet in a static variable, and use that instance in the loop, which cuts down the runtime back down to a much more palatable 9ms over 100M iterations.

So it looks like we have a winner!  Thanks guys for your quick replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you want is an enum set

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html

put the elements you want to test for in the set, and then use the Set method contains().

```
import java.util.EnumSet;


public class EnumSetExample
{
  enum Level { NONE, DEBUG, INFO, ERROR };

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    EnumSet<Level> subset = EnumSet.of(Level.DEBUG, Level.INFO);

    for(Level currentLevel : EnumSet.allOf(Level.class))
    {
      if (subset.contains(currentLevel))
      {
        System.out.println("we have " + currentLevel.toString());
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("we don't have " + currentLevel.toString());
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, see my question edit for some benchmarking on using EnumSet to make sure I did not incur a performance hit.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do it concisely in Java. The closest you can come is to dump the values in a set and call contains(). An EnumSet is probably most efficient in your case. You can shorted the set initialization a little using the double brace idiom, though this has the drawback of creating a new inner class each time you use it, and hence increases the memory usage slightly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, both you and rcook hit the nail on the head, I had to choose one answer, so since he has less points I gave it to him.

Answer (score 1):

In general, logging levels are implemented as integers:

```
public static int LEVEL_NONE  = 0;
public static int LEVEL_DEBUG = 1;
public static int LEVEL_INFO  = 2;
public static int LEVEL_ERROR = 3;
```

and then you can test for severity using simple comparisons:

```
if (Clog._loglevel >= LEVEL_DEBUG) {
    // log
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, the logging level is just a simplified example I thought of. What I am really after is doing it much larger enum lists.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list of required levels, ie:

```
List<ELogLevel> levels = Lists.newArrayList(ELogLevel.Info,
        ELogLevel.Debug, ELogLevel.Error);
if (levels.contains(CLog._logLevel)) {
    //
}
```

Comment: Where does `Lists` come from?